# Cant conect to Firebase API from React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, port, react-native-firebase

I'm doing a full stack application with React Native and Node Express with a Firebase Firestore database.

Everything is almost done; when I try per separate, everything works. For example, the API with Postman works or if I go to the browser works.

The React Native apk, works in my external device but now comes the problem. If iIchange the API to this: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users it works.

When I use my API, it didn't work. Returns:

> Axios Error:Network Error.

I'm using the free Firebase Firestore, maybe is this the problem.

I put down the Firewall just in case and the problem still the same.

First I tried to change the ports; I don't know why but I tried, maybe here is the problem.

This is the code of the API:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

const permisos = require("./permisos.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(permisos),
  databaseURL: "https://url-que-te-da-firestore.firebaseio.com",
});

const db = admin.firestore();

app.use(cors({origin: true}));


exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);

/**
 * Genera un objeto de respuesta con un formato específico.
 *
 * @param {string} codigo - El código de estado de la respuesta.
 * @param {any} entrada - La entrada o resultado de la operación.
 * @return {Object} Objeto de respuesta con un formato específico.
 */
function salida(codigo, entrada) {
  const today = new Date();
  const date = today.getFullYear()+"-"+
    (today.getMonth()+1)+"-"+
    today.getDate()+"|"+
    today.getHours() + ":" +
    today.getMinutes() + ":" +
    today.getSeconds();

  if (codigo === "200") {
    return {
      mensaje: "Proceso terminado exitosamente",
      folio: date,
      resultado: entrada,
    };
  }

  if (codigo === "201") {
    return {
      mensaje: "Elemento creado exitosamente",
      folio: date,
      resultado: entrada,
    };
  }

  if (codigo === "500") {
    return {
      mensaje: "Ocurrio un detalle en el servidor",
      folio: date,
      resultado: entrada,
    };
  }

  return {
    mensaje: "Ocurrio un detalle en el servidor",
    folio: date,
    resultado: entrada,
  };
}

// Añadir libros
app.post("/books", (req, res) => {
  (async () => {
    try {
      await db.collection("books").doc("/" + req.body.id + "/")
          .create({titulo: req.body.titulo});
      return res.status(200).send(salida("200", "Libro creado correctamente"));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(500).send(salida("500", error));
    }
  })();
});


// Leer todos los libros
app.get("/books", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const query = db.collection("books");
    const querySnapshot = await query.get();
    const docs = querySnapshot.docs;

    const response = docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      titulo: doc.data().titulo,
    }));

    return res.status(200).json(salida("200", response));
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json(salida("500", error));
  }
});

// Leer solo 1 libro por id
app.get("/books/:id", (req, res) =>{
  (async () => {
    try {
      const doc = db.collection("books").doc(req.params.id);
      const item = await doc.get();
      const response = item.data();
      return res.status(200).json(salida("200", response));
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).send(salida("500", error));
    }
  })();
});


// Modificar libros
app.put("/books/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const document = db.collection("books").doc(req.params.id);

    await document.update({
      titulo: req.body.titulo,
    });

    return res.status(200).json(salida("200", "El libro ha sido actualizado"));
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json(salida("500", error));
  }
});


// Borrar libros
app.delete("/books/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const doc = db.collection("books").doc(req.params.id);
    await doc.delete();
    return res.status(200).json(salida("200", "El libros ha sido borrado"));
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send(salida("500", error));
  }
});
```

And this is the code of the apk:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import type { FC, ReactNode } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

type SectionProps = {
  title: string;
  children?: ReactNode;
};

const Section: FC<SectionProps> = ({ children, title }) => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  return (
    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionTitle,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? 'white' : 'black',
          },
        ]}>
        {title}
      </Text>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionDescription,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? 'light' : 'dark',
          },
        ]}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const App: FC = () => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  const [dataFromServer, setDataFromServer] = useState<any>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Realizar solicitud HTTP al servidor Node.js al cargar la aplicación
    //http://192.168.1.38:5000/libros-brais/us-central1/app/books
    axios.get("http://192.168.1.38:5000/libros-brais/us-central1/app/books")
      .then(response => {
        setDataFromServer(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? 'darker' : 'lighter',
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
        backgroundColor={backgroundStyle.backgroundColor}
      />
      <ScrollView
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        style={backgroundStyle}>
        {/* ... Otros componentes ... */}
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? 'black' : 'white',
          }}>
          <Section title="Step One">
            Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.tsx</Text> to change this
            screen and then come back to see your edits.
          </Section>
          <Section title="Data from Server">
            <Text>{dataFromServer ? JSON.stringify(dataFromServer) : 'Loading...'}</Text>
          </Section>
          {/* ... Otras secciones ... */}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
});

export default App;
```

When I run ->> firebase serve:

```
Serving from 'C:\Users\r3mus\OneDrive\Escritorio\Proyectos\prueba brais react\prueba-brais'...

i  functions: Watching "C:\Users\r3mus\OneDrive\Escritorio\Proyectos\prueba brais react\prueba-brais\functions" for Cloud Functions...
+  functions: Using node@18 from host.
Serving at port 8292

+  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: app.
+  functions[us-central1-app]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5000/libros-brais/us-central1/app).
!  functions: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.
```

I changed the port of `localhost:5000` to `localhost:8292` in my React request and still not working.

To run the React apk I'm using ->>> npm start because ->>> npx react-native android-run gives an error in React Native 0.73

For the configuration of Firebase I followed the docs of here: https://rnfirebase.io/